# MinGW: "gcc is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, mingw

I downloaded and installed MinGW. I used the graphical program to install the C++ compiler.

Typing `gcc` in the Windows command line prints:

```None
gcc is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I checked, and `gcc.exe` is present in `C:\MinGW\bin`. What's wrong?

Comment: confirm your PATH environment variable in windows contains the mingw\bin path

Comment: Do you know how to add it to your path?  On Windows 7 you click Start and then type "Environment" and then select "Edit environment variables for your account".  Then you just add it to the end of the semi-colon-delimited PATH variable.

Answer (score 57):

Although an old question, none of the answers here helped me. The only route I found to get to my destination is by typing in the following line in my command prompt:

[image]

To copy: set Path=C:\MinGW\bin;%PATH%

After that, simply type in gcc -v.

Hope this helps anyone with the problem I had!

Comment: This works for me, but for some reason every time I close out of command prompt I have to retype this. Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: Hi @LavaMaster, the set in the cmd is temporal. If you don't want that behavior you'll need to follow this guide.https://www.windows-commandline.com/gcc-not-recognized-internal-external-command/

Comment: Hi @SebastianLeandro, I am following the directions from the link you sent me. When I check to see if MinGW is in my path, I noticed that it was already there. I am still unable to use gcc. I get the same error "not recognized as an internal or external command..."

Comment: If you had your console open, you'll need to close it and try again. Make sure that the folder that you added into the path is the /bin folder inside mingw

Comment: Looks like the answer is in here. Because you don't have the uri path to the `MinGW\bin` directory, your machine can't recognize `gcc`. You have to add it to the Path environment variable in your system. You can get to environment variables by just typing environment variables in the Windows search box in your taskbar. When you change an environment variable, make sure you don't delete anything unless you know what you're deleting. If you delete something vital, you could be faced with reinstalling Windows. Using `set` in the CMD only sets the environment variable for that instance.

Answer (score 8):

Or at the command line you must type in "\mingw\bin\gcc" instead of just "gcc". Best to set the environment as mentioned above.

Comment: how to install gcc,  i dont have `\mingw\bin\gcc` directory.

Answer (score 4):

Please edit the Path variable to append a semicolon followed by location "C:\MinGW\bin" and do NOT use any spaces while doing so.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` was empty.
And gcc was installed at `C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin`

So, adding `C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin` to Path variable worked for me.

Comment: this helped me. tks!

Comment: I did a similar thing. I added `export PATH=/ucrt64/bin:$PATH` to `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is obvious, but don't forget that the PATH environment variable is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:
click on "New" under Environmental Variables and add the following line to both user and system variables without editing:

```
C:\mingw32\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```