# GCC issue while using cython

Tags: python, gcc, cython

I am trying to execute a file as shown on this website,
http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html

I have saved my file with `.pyx` extension, made the `setup.py` file and ran `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` command. So earlier I was getting `error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory` and then I installed the package as suggested here [Error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972347/error-command-gcc-failed-no-such-file-or-directory) I added the `C:\users\name\mingw\bin` in my environment variable as suggested [MinGW: "gcc is not recognized as an internal or external command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304916/mingw-gcc-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command). 
Still, when I am typing gcc on cmd it is showing `'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.` 
So, I am confused. I also went into `mingw\bin` and then I run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` but then I get `command 'gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1`.

I am stuck on this. Please help as this is my first time to use Cython.

Comment: this is probably stupid, but have you tried to open another terminal after adding the path?

Comment: It gives the same error `command 'gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1`. Just for reference, I am trying to run the code which is tutorial of kaggle and can be found from github https://github.com/wendykan/DeepLearningMovies/blob/master/Word2Vec_AverageVectors.py

Comment: Did you try downloading MinGW from their website? You could try just downloading the git/mingw package on https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: No, I have downloaded the package as suggested on stackoverflow

Comment: You may need to get someone to help you install gcc to Windows. I've done that on several occasions and it's sometimes a nightmare. At least twice I've just given up and installed Fedora Linux in a virtual machine, because developing with gcc is extraordinarily easy in that case.

Comment: For what it is worth, I personally have found it easy to use the mingw environment provided by installing msys2 instead. That would provide you a convenient terminal to use as well as a package manager that you can use to install Cython. I can definitely vouch that this works for Cython development on Windows 10 while giving you access to a basic, Linux-like development environment without installing a whole distribution :)