# "gcc is not recognized" even after setting PATH variable. What is left?

Tags: c, gcc, windows-10

I had the same problem as in this question: [After installing minGW, gcc command is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923908/after-installing-mingw-gcc-command-is-not-recognized).
I have downloaded MinGW Installer and have followed the instruction that is held in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304916/mingw-gcc-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) and in this [link](https://www.edaboard.com/showthread.php?378070-gcc-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command%20and%20in); however, I still get the same "not recognized" message. What is left to fix?

EDIT: Forgot to add a screenshot.
[screencap of relevant area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHTj4.png)

Comment: If you install mingw-w64, it comes with a batch file and start menu entry that sets up the environment

Comment: Where may I find that?

Comment: https://mingw-w64.org/

Comment: it's better to copy the error text and paste here instead of a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked your path in the windows GUI? Search in windows (Windows+S) for "environment variables" and click "edit the system environment variables." Then click environment variables (the button). Add the path to your MinGW/bin (binaries) folder to your **system** PATH variable!! (not user). Try this.

If you have, you will need to close your cmd window and open a new one, as well as possibly needing to restart/sign out and sign in.

Also make sure you installed the gcc part of MinGW and not just g++ compiler (I can't remember the install options right now).

Comment: I have the gcc part. I edited the system Path variable (under the name of "Path," not "PATH," so maybe it was the wrong part). Apparently, I have minGW 32. Does that change anything?

Comment: my advice would be NOT to change the system path  , just set up the path for each shell where you are going to use the compiler  .  If you change the system path then it is very difficult to have more than one compiler installed

Comment: Do you have a directory like `C:\MinGW\bin` ??

Comment: If you cd into that folder: a) is there a "gcc.exe" file b) can you run gcc from there?